# Flyway migration with single schema and multiple projects

Tags: flyway

I have a question related to Flyway DB Migrations. How to generally manage multiple projects (microservices) dealing with the same DB schema. The Flyway migration scripts in each of the project does not allow to start if it is modified by the other project. Do they have any documentation or best practices on the same?

Comment: Ideally each microservice should manage its own data and have separate DB schema. It is a bad practice and breaks the rules of microservice architecture to share DB schema between the services.

Comment: Although your point is valid that DB schema should be managed (include migrations) by a single module, it can be shared by many modules. Microservices architecture with shared DB is not something new and I believe is the widely used architecture in more than thousands of usecases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For what it is worth, this is what we did. Since the schema was shared by multiple projects we had the schema managed by a single project whose task was to maintain said schema. Centralizing schema creation and maintenance had other benefits in that we had single locus of change. We needn't scan several projects for changes.

I honestly think this is the best solution. I don't believe flyway has inter-project schema dependency management.

Comment: Did this separate project contain only the Flyway config and migration files, or did you also move all application SQL statements (the normal `SELECT`s and so on) to this central project?

Comment: To answer Anders Thorbeck's question, we only moved the flyway config and migration files and not the SQL. The SQL/JPQL statements for our product were held within the J2EE Entity Beans for what it is worth.

Answer (score 19):

We are in the process of doing this. We have one central project that manages the schema creation/management, and other projects handle their own function creations all via their own flyway versioning. This is done by changing the name of the table that those other projects check their schema version against, and setting baseline on migrate to `true`. We are using spring/flyway-db configuration so this was simply adding the following to `application.properties` for each project in addition to the first.

```
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
flyway.table=schema_version_*<some_other_identifier>*
```

I know your question did not specify a spring configuration explicitly, but I believe this can be configured not matter how you are using flyway. I wanted to post an answer as when I was googling the question myself, your SO question was the top result, and I figured my answer might help someone down the track.

Comment: How do you manage objects created by different projects referencing each other?

Answer (score 2):

if any one using the Play frame work this problem can be tackle with independent flyway history tables for each microservice mean every mircoservice has its own flyway history table with name according to service. this ll create flyway table for each service
add these properties in conf file for changing the flyway table name.

```
db.default.migration.table=microservice1    for 1 mircoservice
db.default.migration.table=microservice2    for 2 mircoservice
```

add this property in every microservice conf file
this is only for play frame work

Comment: This should work independent of Play or any other framework as Flyway can be configured to use a different *history* table name.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue, because I was working with 2-3 micro services, So what I did is as below
example, running in following sequence

```
micro-service-1 ( which required migration )
micro-service-2
micro-service-3 ( which required migration )
```

So I created flyway migration v1__description.sql in micro-service-1 and then in micro-service-3 I created v1_2__description.sql because it is at 3rd in sequence of running projects, this is my release version 1, which are having 2 migration with version 1 and 1.2

```
micro-service-1 ( V1_description.sql )
micro-service-2 // if in future it reuires migration then we can use, V<<currentVersion>>_1__description.sql
micro-service-3 ( V1_2_description.sql )
```

Answer (score 0):

For Microservice Architecture(or Two different Project),

If two different microservice needs to be connected with the database then we need to make two different schemas because as per microservice architecture is two different microservice is connected to different schemas(different database).

like,

- Microservice-1 --> schema-1
- Microservice-2 --> schema-2

due to this flywayDB maintain each microservice flywayDB migration history on each schema, so due to this case flyway DB works

Comment: The question asked was very specific about dealting with *one* db schema only.

Answer (score 0):

By creating another schema table using below code,

spring.flyway.table=flyway_schema_history_microserive1

spring.flyway.table=flyway_schema_history_microserive2

In addition the microservices should be implemented seperate as db